# Heroku pg:restore failing to find dump file?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, amazon-s3, pg-restore

I am having troubles restoring my backups to the heroku database via an external dump file.  I run this command:

```
heroku pg:backups:restore 'https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/some-bucket/some-dump.dump' DATABASE_URL
```

And I get this error in return:

```
Backup 'https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/some-bucket/some-dump.dump' not found for some-heroku-app
```

I can access the file from the browser, but it seems that pg:backups can't access the file.  I've also tried different methods of hosting the file (including a private FTP server and Dropbox).I've searched for other people with the same problems, but none of the questions seemed to be answered

Comment: Does no one know what is causing this?

Comment: What do you get when you `curl` the dumpfile?

Comment: I don't know what/how to do that